# Best Javascript string search and return techniques in this case?

Tags: javascript, regex, string, search

I've got a string coming into a func which may be:

```
I am a "somevalue"
```

or

```
I am a "somevalue" of "anothervalue"
```

In each case I need to recognise the 'I am a' part, and then return the value inside the quotes, or both if there are two. There are a few ways to do this but I'm looking for the most efficient at high usage.

Interested to hear from anyone who has input on this - thanks!

Comment: Regex can do the job, yes, but you'll have to define "high usage". Can you process your strings server side in batches instead? What are you trying to do?

Comment: Thanks, any starting suggestions on regex to do this?

@Vache "high usage" means it will have a high number of calls. It's a nodejs background app running on Linux.

Comment: The two examples you gave...are these the complete strings? So would it be save to say, that you essentially just want all values inside quotes?

Comment: How are quotes escaped within quotes?

Comment: @basilikum yes they are complete strings. I'm looking for all values inside quotes, but only if the exact pattern 'i am a ' is found first, and also the second value in quotes if ' of ' is found after the first value in quotes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since your format is constant, you can match and capture in the same regex.

```
var str1 = 'I am a "somevalue" of "anothervalue"',
    str2 = 'I am a "somevalue"',
    str3 = 'I am a "value with \\"escaped\\" quotes"',
    regex = /^I am a "((?:\\"|[^"])*)"(?: of "((?:\\"|[^"])*)")?/;

function match(str) {
    var matches = str.match(regex);
    if (matches !== null) {
        console.log(matches.slice(1)); // ["somevalue", "anothervalue"]
    }
}

match(str1); // ["somevalue", "anothervalue"]
match(str2); // ["somevalue", undefined]
match(str3); // ["value with \"escaped\" quotes", undefined]
```

The slice call is to remove the first match which contains the entire string. You will get 'undefined" as the second match if there was nothing to match.

Depending on how quotes-within-quotes are going to be escaped, you might have to modify the regex a bit. I assumed `\` was going to be the escape character.

```
NODE                     EXPLANATION
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  ^                        the beginning of the string
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  I am a "                 'I am a "'
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  (                        group and capture to \1:
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    (?:                      group, but do not capture (0 or more
                             times (matching the most amount
                             possible)):
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
      \\                       '\'
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
      "                        '"'
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
     |                        OR
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
      [^"]                     any character except: '"'
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    )*                       end of grouping
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  )                        end of \1
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  "                        '"'
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  (?:                      group, but do not capture (optional
                           (matching the most amount possible)):
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
     of "                    ' of "'
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    (                        group and capture to \2:
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
      (?:                      group, but do not capture (0 or more
                               times (matching the most amount
                               possible)):
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
        \\                       '\'
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
        "                        '"'
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
       |                        OR
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
        [^"]                     any character except: '"'
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
      )*                       end of grouping
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    )                        end of \2
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    "                        '"'
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  )?                       end of grouping
```

With all that being said, this solution is only viable for a certain value of "high usage". If we're talking millions of queries at a very high rate you'll be better off with technology better suited for parsing text (and that will probably not be in JavaScript/node).

Comment: Nice explanation of the regex :)

Comment: This may fail if there are escaped slashes before quotes - easy solution is to prefix an `\\\\|` in your non-capture group

Comment: @Vache thanks, I was able to use this solution and base other behaviours on the values of the returned array. The escaping of quotes worked fine (input string comes from twitter api).